# How to get records in descending order in QLDB?

Tags: database, amazon-qldb

**Select * from Transactions where id='123'**

I am trying to get transactions in descending order . But order by is not working here .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing this answer, QLDB does not support the "ORDER BY" clause. To learn more about QLDB supported PartiQL query language, you can reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html